# nginx + fast-cgi - how to make phpmyadmin work

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, fastcgi

I've configured my nginx server + php. Eeverything works fine, except phpmyadmin.

I googled a lot and found some alias tricks, but they didn't work to me.

That works great:

```
        location ~ ^/ololo/(.*\.php)$ {
                alias $root_path/img/$1;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        }

        location /ololo/ {
                alias $root_path/img/;
                index index.php;
        }
```

There is `img` directory in my site path and when I request `sitename/ololo/` or `sitename/ololo/index.php` everything is fine.

But that:

```
         location ~ ^/myadmin/(.*\.php)$ {
                alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/$1;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

        }

        location /myadmin/ {
                alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
                index index.php;
        }
```

won't work!

when I'm trying to request `mysite/myadmin/` or `mysite/myadmin/index.php` server throws me

> No input file specified.

error message. In `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/` are all `.php` files.

What's wrong with my `nginx.conf`?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so according to what I understood from your replies I'm modifying this answer, Add this to your main server and it should work.

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    root /usr/share/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Ok so a down vode made me take a look at this again, It's been a while since I've wrote this answer and I should say this isn't how I'd write the config file if it was today, here's the config that I would use.

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    index index.php index.htm;
    root /usr/share;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

if you want to use alias then replace the `phpmyadmin` block with this

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    index index.php index.htm;
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
}
```

**Note:** If your server block already contains the `index` then you don't need to redefine it inside the `phpmyadmin` block.

Comment: Did you try the symlink ? should work as long as you have a working default server. should be something like
`ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/` ( or where ever your files are located )
would make the `domain.com/phpmyadmin` accessible

Comment: ok so to be specific, is this a local host or a server with a domain? and are you trying to access it by (localhost/example.com)/phpmyadmin ?

Comment: it is VPS(centos6 + nginx + php + ispmanager) with domain. trying to access example.com/phpmyadmin/   (i put symlink in the site directory)

Comment: wow, that works fine, but why same code with alias wont work? i dont get it :(

Answer (score 0):

read the comment the order must be exact, if still error read the error.log

```
### first define phpmyadmin static files
location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js|woff|ttf)$ {
        root /usr/share/;
        expires max;
        #log_not_found off;
}

### then your public_html static file   
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js|woff|ttf)$ {
        root /path/public_html;
        expires max;
        #log_not_found off;
}
```

because phpmyadmin path outside public_html so you need try_files to redirect slash **"/"** to **"/index.php"**

```
location /phpmyadmin {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /phpmyadmin/index.php?$args;
}
```

and now the last, fastcgi

```
### Define phpmyadmin PHP files
location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.*)\.php$ {
    ## optional, try uncomment if error
    #root /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

### then your public_html files 
location ~ \.php$ {
    ##optional, try uncomment if error
    #root           /path/public_html;

    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /path/public_html/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

now you can access phpmyadmin on `http://yoursite/phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 0):

This is my config:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    alias   /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php;
    location ~ /([^/]+\.php)$ {
        try_files /$1 =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        location ~ /phpmyadmin/js/([^/]+\.php)$ {
            try_files /phpmyadmin/js/$1 =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```